# How to replace last character in String when it is in an Array

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

If some String ends with a character that is in `arrayOf(X, Y, Z)` I want to replace it with new char `A`. I don't know how to do this, and everything I've tried doesn't work.

Comment: To be sure. If the String ends with `X`, `Y`, `Z` You want to replace this last character to `A`. Otherwise, You don't want to do anything?

Comment: Absolutely right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this like this:

```
var test = "Some string Z"

if (test.lastOrNull() in arrayOf('X', 'Y', 'Z')) //check if the last char == 'X' || 'Y' || 'Z'
{
    test = test.dropLast(1) + 'A' // if yes replace with `A`
}

println(test) // "Some string A"
```

---

Or with using extension function:

```
fun String.replaceLast(toReplace: CharArray, newChar: Char): String
{
    if (last() in toReplace)
    {
        return dropLast(1) + 'A'
    }
    return this
}

//Test
val oldTest = "Some string Z"
val newTest = oldTest.replaceLast(charArrayOf('X', 'Y', 'Z'), 'A')

println(newTest) // "Some string A"
```

Comment: instead of `substring(0, test.length - 1)` you can use `dropLast(1)`

Comment: first one is better. Thank you!

Comment: @Stachu It looks better with `dropLast(1)`, I edited my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I tested my app now, `dropLast(1)` doesn't works, it deletes last character when `dropLast(2)`, don't you know the reason?

Comment: Maybe it is because the string is empty at some point in Your app? I have tested with `dropLast(1)` and it works

Comment: Now I'm getting _e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Failed to generate expression: KtBlockExpression_ when I inserted the first variation in my code

Comment: @Lλmbdλ I have no idea why this happens :/ I think You should ask a new question to reach more users and also You should include all essential parts of the code

Comment: `test.isNotEmpty() && test.last()` can be replaced with `test.lastOrNull()`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 haven't known about this method, I edited the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Simply use this regexp:

```
val regEx = "[XYZ]$".toRegex()
val result = initialString.replace(regexp,"A")
```

`$` in regex means last character of a string

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of [lastIndexOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/last-index-of.html) and [dropLast](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/drop-last.html) functions of String class:

```kotlin
private fun replaceLastChar(original: String, replacement: Char = 'A'): String {
    if (original.lastIndexOf('Z')
        + original.lastIndexOf('X')
        + original.lastIndexOf('Y') > 0
    ) {
        return original.dropLast(1) + replacement
    }
    return original
}
```