# If last character of String cointains this array Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, jvm

`If` (some String ends with a character that is in `arrayOf(X, Y, Z)`){
do...
}
Tried to use

```
var test = "Some string Z"

if (test.isNotEmpty() && test.last() in arrayOf('X', 'Y', 'Z')) //check if the last char == 'X' || 'Y' || 'Z'
{
    test = test.dropLast(1) + 'A' // if yes replace with `A`
}
```

but android gives an compiling error :

> e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM)
> Internal error:

searching for any other solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace last character in String when it is in an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63669460/how-to-replace-last-character-in-string-when-it-is-in-an-array)

Comment: Please check the answers in the original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63669460/how-to-replace-last-character-in-string-when-it-is-in-an-array

Comment: I've asked this question, and none of these helped me

Comment: If your question is about the compilation exception, that should be in the title of your question. Otherwise, this looks like a duplicate of your existing question and this will likely be closed.

Comment: This code runs fine in Android Studio.

Comment: "Back-end (JVM) Internal error" is likely not a problem in your code, but rather a bug in the compiler. Could you report the entire exception message to https://kotl.in/issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use regex

```
var test = "Some string Z"
val array = arrayOf('X', 'Y', 'Z')
if (test.matches(".*(${array.joinToString("|")})$".toRegex())) {
    test = test.dropLast(1) + 'A'
}
```

Bonus with ignoring case sensitivity

```
//...
val array = arrayOf('x', 'Y', 'z')
if (test.matches(".*(${array.joinToString("|")})$".toRegex(RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE))) {
//...
```

Comment: Did you specify the last character?
I want to change only the last charaqter if it contains an array

Comment: @Lλmbdλ this will search only for last char